# How to solve instamojo integration API error issue

Tags: payment, instamojo

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Instamojo\Exceptions\ApiException' not found in /home/pwvcbaro/public_html/events.cglportal-icai.org/js/insta/Utilities.php:98 Stack trace: #0 /home/pwvcbaro/public_html/events.cglportal-icai.org/js/insta/Instamojo.php(301): api_request('POST', 'https‍://api.ins...', Array, Array) #1 /home/pwvcbaro/public_html/events.cglportal-icai.org/js/insta/Instamojo.php(434): Instamojo\Instamojo->request_api_data('POST', 'v2/payment_requ...', Array) #2 /home/pwvcbaro/public_html/events.cglportal-icai.org/member_pay_page.php(51): Instamojo\Instamojo->createPaymentRequest(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/pwvcbaro/public_html/events.cglportal-icai.org/js/insta/Utilities.php on line 98

instamojo API integration on error